# what is incorrect about my solution or my output method for codejam exercise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, output, logic

I participated in kickstart of google code jam contest and got stuck in problem 1A called  Gbus count
My code is passing the sample test case provided in the problem but when I submit the small input by outputting it to a file it gives me an error, incorrect response.

Problem link - [https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4374486/dashboard#s=p0](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4374486/dashboard#s=p0%22here%22)

```
t=int(input())    #no. of test cases 
for test in range(t):
    if test==0:
        n=int(input())
    else:
        input()     #to cover up the blank line after each test case
        n=int(input())
    l=list(map(int,input().split()))

    buses={}      # the route of each bus will be stored in this dictionary
    i=1

    for d in l:       # this loop is used to store the route of each bus in the buses dictionary
        if i not in buses:
            buses[i]=[d]
        elif len(buses[i])<2:
            buses[i].append(d)
        else:
            i=i+1
            buses[i]=[d]

    p=int(input())
    cities={}
             #this dictionary will contain the cities which need to be monitored
    for _ in range(p):     #first each city is initialized to zero
        cities[int(input())]=0

    for city in cities:       #Monitor all buses in each city if it falls in the route range than increment the city
        for bus in buses:
            if buses[bus][0]<=city<=buses[bus][1]:
                cities[city]+=1
    result=[]

    for city in cities:      #store all the cities in a list
        result.append(cities[city])

    print("Case #{}: {}".format(test+1, ' '.join(map(str,result))))
```

**My logic:**

First I took all the test cases in a variable t and for each test case  I inputted the no. of buses and inputted routes of all buses in a list l. Then I created a dictionary named buses and divided the list into n lists with each list for each bus nume=beres from 1 to n in the dictionary.

Then I inputted all the cities to be monitored in another dictionary named cities and initialized the value of each city to be monitored to 0.

Finally, I calculated the no. of buses travelling through each city by checking if it falls in the route range of each bus and if it does I incremented the value of the corresponding city by 1 and then stored all the values of the dictionary in a list and outputted it for each test case.

**Output methodology:**

I used this line to execute my code using cmd in my working directory

```
python gbus_count.py < A-small-attempt3.in > output.out
```

My code works fine for the sample test case provided so there might not be a flaw in my logic. I think that there might be a mistake in my output methodology.

Comment: Install Idle python on pc and you can run program by just pressing f5.
If your program is incorrect then it shows the error and line at which error occured.All you need is you should know error detection

Comment: Since this is a practice exercise, if you are interested, i can add my solution to my answer below. (I didn't add it initially as it can spoil your thoughts).

Comment: @Anubis yeah, sure I would like to see the better way of solving this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code.

1. Python standard dictionary is not ordered! Therefore the `cities` dictionary will not have the elements (keys) in the order you entered.

   - From `Python 3.1` onwards, you can use the [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) for this
2. If the same city is repeated twice (or more), there will be only one entry in the final result, because a dictionary can't hold repeated keys.

As I see your design has flows. Besides, I think you could have done this much easily without making things too complicated.

---

**Note:**
From Python 3.6 onwards, the standard dictionary maintains the insertion order by default.

---

**UPDATE**

As requested, following is my attempt to solve the problem.

Please note that this might not be the best solution! And for sure, this is not the most readable solution. This is just my solution.

```
for case in range(1, int(input())+1):
    if case > 1:
        input('\n') # consume and print newline
    print("Case #{}:".format(case), end='')
    bus_count = int(input())
    busline = list(map(int, input().strip().split(" ")))
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        city = int(input())
        matches = sum([1 for bid in range(bus_count) if busline[2*bid] <= city <= busline[2*bid+1]])
        print(" {}".format(matches), end='')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes, I have one more doubt are my output methodologies correct?

Comment: please be precise, what did you mean?

Comment: `python gbus_count.py < A-small-attempt3.in > output.out` Is this command correct to output the code

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Refer to [google codejam quick start guide](https://code.google.com/codejam/resources/quickstart-guide#io-tutorial) for more details

Answer (score 0):

you can also check out this solution:

```
def Gbus_Count():
    T = int(input())
    for i in range(T):
        if i == 0:
            N = int(input())
        else:
            input()
            N = int(input())
        A = list(map(int, input().split()))
        P = int(input())
        C = list()
        D = dict()
        for k in range(P):
            C.append(int(input()))
        for m in range(P):
            for n in range(N):
                if A[2*n]<=C[m]<=A[2*n+1]:
                    if C[m] not in D:
                        D[C[m]] = 1
                    else:
                        D[C[m]] += 1
        print("Case #{}: {}".format(i+1, ' '.join(str(x) for x in D.values())))
Gbus_Count()
```